# ASP.NET MVC - Create 2 Urls to the same Controller and action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I is it possible to create a url aliasing for a controller/action without creating a new controller?

mypage.com/Hello/World

I want that the page

mypage.com/Hi/Universe

will actually show the content of /Hello/World with how creating a Hi controller.

Thanks

**Update**

I have a controller:
`OpenRealAccountController` with action `Start`.
I want to rout `GlobalAccount/StepOne` to show the contents of: `OpenRealAccount/Start`
This is what I have added to the method: `RegisterRoutes`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "GlobalOnBoarding_Change",
              "GlobalAccount/StepOne",
              new { controller = "OpenRealAccount", action = "Start" });
```

The problem is that I am getting : `"The resource cannot be found."`

Comment: More than likely, you placed your MapRoute after the default route.  It must come before.

Comment: Your update is an entirely new question, and should be asked as such.  The answer provided answers your first question, and you should ask the second question provided in your update as new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use routing in the global.asax.cs file:

- Define a route for `hello/world` that points to the controller and
  action
- Define a route for `hi/universe` that also points to the same
  controller action

An example would be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "helloWorld",
              "hello/world",
              new { controller = "HelloWorld", action = "index" });

routes.MapRoute(
              "hiUniverse",
              "hi/universe",
              new { controller = "HelloWorld", action = "index" });
```

Comment: The only down side to having two routes to the same action is that all of the Html / Url helper methods are going to choose the first route that is found to match